# How to make changes to a /system/framework files in an android SDK emulator (API > 25)?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, smali

I'm trying to make a few slight modifications to some /system/framework files in an Oreo SDK emulator (API 26).
I want to make changes in the boot-framework.vdex file.

I've managed to extract it via the vdexExtractor (`https://github.com/anestisb/vdexExtractor`), and managed to

- extract the dex file (`boot-framework_classes2.dex`)
- extract the smali code from `boot-framework_classes2.dex`

Though, I can't find the way to recompile it back to `.dex` and than back to `.vdex`, and I'm not sure that my previous steps were correct.

I'm trying to figure out what are the exact steps and tools I should use and do.

Thanks.